# Apex Interactive Grid how to retrieve a specific record

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am retrieving my grid data using:

```
var ig$ = apex.region("myGrid1").widget(),
                view = ig$.interactiveGrid("getCurrentView");
```

Now I want to check for a specific record based on 2 columns: `id1` and `id2` where `id1 = 1` and `id2 = 7`

How can I do that with javascript?

Comment: Don't use the Salesforce `apex` tag for `oracle-apex` questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate for each record like this:

```
//"myGrid1" should be the static id of the IG region
var widget      = apex.region('myGrid1').widget();
var grid        = widget.interactiveGrid('getViews','grid');  
var model       = grid.model; 
var results     = [];

model.forEach(function(r) {
    var record = r;

    //the name of the columns should be ID1 and ID2, if not
    //make the necessary changes using "_" to represent "space"
    var value1 = model.getValue(record,'ID1');
    var value2 = model.getValue(record,'ID2');

    if(value1 == 1 && value2 == 7) {
      results.push(record);
    }

})

console.log(results);
```

To test this code, execute it on console.

To start the console on chrome just press F12

good luck.

Comment: hi. Could you please take a look at my new question? I ran into a limitation with character cut off for javascript code

Comment: Is it possible to use some() or every() instead of forEach() to loop through an interactive grid?  I'm needing a way to break out of the loop when the IF condition is met and unable to do this with a forEach.  - Thanks!